# pandas multi Index from columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe like this:

```
          index        A   B   C                  
     01.01.2000        a1  b1  c1
     01.02.2000        a2  b2  c2
     01.03.2000        a3  b3  c3
```

and would like to get this:

```
              index      X
     (0, 01.01.2000)     a1
     (0, 01.02.2000)     a2
     (0, 01.03.2000)     a3
     (1, 01.01.2000)     b1
     (1, 01.02.2000)     b2
     (1, 01.03.2000)     b3
     (2, 01.01.2000)     c1
     (2, 01.02.2000)     c2
     (2, 01.03.2000)     c3
```

I need it this way to run the data through some regression models. The pandas docs on multi indexing unfortunately are very confusing to me as I'm new to this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try of getting the categorical codes of columns, followed by stacking and converging index to tuple

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().astype('category').cat.codes
df1 = df.stack().reorder_levels([1,0]).sort_index()
df1.index = tuple(df1.index)
```

Out:

```
(0, 01.01.2000)    a1
(0, 01.02.2000)    a2
(0, 01.03.2000)    a3
(1, 01.01.2000)    b1
(1, 01.02.2000)    b2
(1, 01.03.2000)    b3
(2, 01.01.2000)    c1
(2, 01.02.2000)    c2
(2, 01.03.2000)    c3
dtype: object
```

** Edit **

Sorting the data based on index levels

```
df.index  = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().astype('category').cat.codes
df1 = df.stack().reorder_levels([1,0]).sort_index(level=1)
df1.index = tuple(df1.index)
```

Out:

```
(0, 2000-01-01 00:00:00)    a1
(1, 2000-01-01 00:00:00)    b1
(2, 2000-01-01 00:00:00)    c1
(0, 2000-01-02 00:00:00)    a2
(1, 2000-01-02 00:00:00)    b2
(2, 2000-01-02 00:00:00)    c2
(0, 2000-01-03 00:00:00)    a3
(1, 2000-01-03 00:00:00)    b3
(2, 2000-01-03 00:00:00)    c3
dtype: object
```

Comment: I like this one too

Comment: This works great except i need the output sorted as in the other examples ( all values from column A followed by values from column B

Comment: Thanks, one step closer:) the data is now sorted by the first argument of the multi index, however its not sorted by the second one(date), do you know how to fix this? ( for example in the output series all the a values are not ordered by date)

Comment: Sort index actually sorts using both index levels, if you want to sort on individual levels, you can specify the level on which the frame should be sorted :-) @MicheleNg

Answer (score 3):

You need `reset_index` two times then just doing `melt`

```
s=df.reset_index().reset_index().melt(['level_0','index'])
yourdf=pd.DataFrame({'index':tuple(zip(s['level_0'],s['index'])),'X':s.value})
yourdf
Out[130]: 
             index   X
0  (0, 01.01.2000)  a1
1  (1, 01.02.2000)  a2
2  (2, 01.03.2000)  a3
3  (0, 01.01.2000)  b1
4  (1, 01.02.2000)  b2
5  (2, 01.03.2000)  b3
6  (0, 01.01.2000)  c1
7  (1, 01.02.2000)  c2
8  (2, 01.03.2000)  c3
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame([
    [(i, idx), v]
    for i, (idx, *V) in enumerate(df.itertuples())
    for v in V
], columns=['index', 'X'])

             index   X
0  (0, 01.01.2000)  a1
1  (0, 01.01.2000)  b1
2  (0, 01.01.2000)  c1
3  (1, 01.02.2000)  a2
4  (1, 01.02.2000)  b2
5  (1, 01.02.2000)  c2
6  (2, 01.03.2000)  a3
7  (2, 01.03.2000)  b3
8  (2, 01.03.2000)  c3
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different way,

```
new_df = df.set_index('index', append=True).stack().droplevel(2)
new_df.index = tuple(zip(new_df.index))
new_df = new_df.reset_index().rename(columns = {'level_0': 'index', 0:'X'})

    index           X
0   (0, 01.01.2000) a1
1   (0, 01.01.2000) b1
2   (0, 01.01.2000) c1
3   (1, 01.02.2000) a2
4   (1, 01.02.2000) b2
5   (1, 01.02.2000) c2
6   (2, 01.03.2000) a3
7   (2, 01.03.2000) b3
8   (2, 01.03.2000) c3
```